# No job functions found in Azure Functions project (.NET standard 2.0) local

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm trying to create a Azure Functions project in .NET standard 2.0 because I need to use a .NET standard 2.0 class library in this project.

However when I try to create a simple Azure Functions project and run it locally, I get the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsG4X.png

As I said before my code is very basic but I'll share it anyway.

My .csproj file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQBDK.png

My Queue Trigger:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OKC0.png

My Program.cs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTSSj.png

(I'm sorry for the links, I can't post images yet)

Comment: I tried running it with Powershell and from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You don't have to target Function App project to .NET Standard in order to use .NET Standard libraries. You can do that from a project targeting Full Framework (`net461`).
2. If you want to target .NET Standard, you need 2.0/Core version (still in preview) of Azure Functions tools to be able to run them. You can install these by running `npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@core` and then running `func start` from your `publish` folder. Note that this `func` will be in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\npm`, not `%APPDATA%\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.7` as in your example.
3. If you want to run .NET Standard project from Visual Studio, you need 15.5 version preview, see [Improvements to Azure Functions in Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/11/15/improvements-to-azure-functions-in-visual-studio/).
4. Please remove `Program.cs`: it's not needed for Functions project.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you for the clear and detailed answer.